# Proper Instructions to get Asymptote working in MikTeX LaTeX to create inline Graphs

Tags: latex, miktex, asymptote

I have installed MitTeX on W10. Asymptote is installed in MikTeX in folder ..\miktex\bin\x64\asy.exe  When I start this on the command line, I can give an Asymptote command like draw((0,0)--(10,0)); and a file out.eps will immediately be created with the correct asymptote drawing. In the MitKeX console I also installed the asyfig and asymptote packages. When I create with texworks the following Latex doc and use either pdfLatex, xeLatex or luaLatex, just a blank page with a pagenumber and the capture test is created but without any asymptote picture displayed in it. I also tried

latex test.tex
asy test-1.asy
latex test.tex

But this only resulted into a blank square pdf file to be created. Is there some configurations I am missing?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \begin{asy}
     draw((0,0)--(10,0));
     draw((10,0)--(0,10));
    \end{asy}
    \caption{test figure}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I used latex, pdflatex, xelatex and lualatex but none of them seem to work and create the asymptote image